# Cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, swing, object, derby

I wrote this code to set the a jTable to a model to suit the data that would be returned from my query. I am not sure why this is happening but I do have an example of the same code in use and it works perfectly.
 Note: the query calls records from a table that is linked to another table.
 Note: Some may say this is a duplicate question but I feel not becuase Ilooked at that question and non of the solutions helped me, I tried using the iterator instead but same error occurs.
Any suggestions.

This is the code

```
public void createModelsAndEquipmentTableModel(){
        Query query = FinancialDBPUEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Stocktbl t WHERE t.chemical = FALSE");
        List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
        String headings[] = {"Product ID", "Product Name", "Number In Stock", "Number Needs Replacing"};
        Object data[][] = new Object[results.size()][headings.length];
        int index = 0;
        for(Object[] obj: results){// error occurs here.
            data[index++] = obj;
        }
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headings);
        tblquipment.setModel(model);
    }
```

This is the Relevant portion of the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: GUIPac.Stocktbl cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at GUIPac.ViewStockInfo.createChemicalsTableModel(ViewStockInfo.java:53)
    at GUIPac.ViewStockInfo.<init>(ViewStockInfo.java:30)
```

Comment: is that compile time or runtime error....what is the return type of `query.getResultList();`..???

Comment: runtime error, the return type is List but the error is occurring at the for-each loop.

Comment: Only `List`? Without a generic type?

Comment: So how do you know that this list contains `Object[]` and nothing else? Have you checked that?

Comment: Well, the exception message is pretty obvious (if you have experience in programming), the method `getResultList()` returns a `List` of `GUIPac.Stocktbl` and not `Object[]`. If you want `Object[]` instead, then you need to convert the type manually. Like in slartidans answer.

Comment: I do have have experience in programming, I did understand that at first, but be honest If you saw the code I have working which I got from a sample project, wouldn't you be interested why when you use the same code with the same imports, IDE, jdk, and other libraries wouldn't you feel a bit odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query `"SELECT t FROM Stocktbl t WHERE t.chemical = FALSE"` will return `Stocktbl` objects.
When iterating over the ResultList this causes ClassCastExceptions.

I would recommend to use this createQuery-Method:

```
    TypedQuery<Stocktbl> query = FinancialDBPUEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Stocktbl t WHERE t.chemical = FALSE", Stocktbl.class);
```

and then resolve all compiler warnings and errors.

If you need an Object Array, you will have to produce it manually, when using JPA. Here is a pseudo-code for creating these Object Arrays:

```
    for(Stocktbl stock : results){// no error occurs here anymore.
        Object[] obj = new Object[] {stock.ProductId, stock.ProductName, stock.NumberInStock, stock.numberNeedsReplacing};
        data[index++] = obj;
    }
```

please change field names of `Stocktbl stock` to fit to your `Stocktbl` class

Comment: For TypedQuery catch :) +1

Comment: This doesn't help. I need to cast the Result List to an Object[], to get data ready for jTable.

Answer (score 2):

The `getResultList()`- method get back a List of `List<Stocktbl>` not of `Object[]`.

In runtime there is no generic. But when you iterate over it the cast fails.